# PWM controlled LED using VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I've written the following VHDL code and test-bench to control the brightness of LEDs. Then tried with Altera ModelSim to simulate the code. However, I'm facing some technical difficulties. It would be really nice if someone will compile the code and share me the simulated result with me. Thanks in advance.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity main_testbench is
end main_testbench;

architecture behavior of main_testbench is
    component led_controller is 
        Port (  clk, reset: in std_logic;                   -- system clock is assumed 10KHz 
                in_word: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- LS 4 bits - frequency & MS 4 bits - duty-cycle   
                LEDs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));    
    end component;

    signal clk, reset:  std_logic := '0';
    signal in_word:     std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00010001"; -- 0.2 Hz, 10% duty cycle
    signal LEDs:        std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";

    type in_word_commands is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal in_words: in_word_commands := ("00010001", "00010010", "00010100", "00011000", -- 10% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
                                          "00100001", "00100010", "00100100", "00101000", -- 30% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
                                          "01000001", "01000010", "01000100", "01001000", -- 60% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz 
                                          "10000001", "10000010", "10000100", "10001000"); -- 85% duty cycle with 0.2Hz, 0.5Hz, 1Hz, 2Hz
    signal command_num : integer := 0;

begin
    dut: led_controller port map (clk, reset, in_word, LEDs);

    clk <= not clk after 50 us; -- 0.1ms/2 = 50us  
    command_num <= command_num + 1 after 5000 ms; -- 5000ms = 5s 
    in_word <= in_words(command_num); 
end behavior;
```

controller:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity led_controller is
    Port (  clk, reset: in std_logic;                    
            in_word: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   
            LEDs: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end led_controller;

architecture behavior of led_controller is
    --------------------- signals ---------------------
    type freq is array (0 to 3) of integer range 0 to 50000;
    signal frq: freq := (25000, 10000, 5000, 2500);      
    signal led_freq_count: integer range 0 to 50000 := frq(0);

    type d is array (0 to 3) of integer range 0 to 100;
    signal duty: d := (10, 30, 60, 85);      
    signal duty_cycle: integer range 0 to 100 := duty(0);        
    signal LED_switch, new_command: std_logic := '0';
begin

    --------- clock process / sync reset configuration ---------------
    process (clk)
        variable duty_counter: integer range 0 to 100 := 100;
        variable freq_counter: integer range 0 to 50000 := led_freq_count;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            ------- if reset was high or new in_word were arrived --------

            if reset = '1' or new_command = '1' then
                LEDs <= "0000";
                duty_counter := 100;
                freq_counter := led_freq_count;
                new_command <= '0';
            else  
            ------- blinking process --------

                if freq_counter = 0 then 
                   freq_counter := led_freq_count;
                   LED_switch <= not LED_switch;
                end if;
                freq_counter := freq_counter - 1;

                if duty_counter = 0 then 
                   duty_counter := 100;
                end if;
                duty_counter := duty_counter - 1;

                ------ output assignment -------
                if LED_switch = '1' and duty_counter < duty_cycle then
                    LEDs <= "1111";
                else 
                    LEDs <= "0000";
                end if;
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process;

    --------- input process---------------
    process (in_word)
    begin
        case in_word(3 downto 0) is
            when "0001" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(0);
            when "0010" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(1);
            when "0100" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(2);
            when "1000" =>   led_freq_count <= frq(3);
            when others =>   led_freq_count <= frq(0);
        end case;
        case in_word(7 downto 4) is
            when "0001" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(0);
            when "0010" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(1);
            when "0100" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(2);
            when "1000" =>   duty_cycle <= duty(3);
            when others =>   duty_cycle <= duty(0);
        end case; 
        new_command    <= '1';
    end process;


end behavior;
```

Comment: ? What problems are you facing?

Comment: The LED output is null which shouldn't be the case

Comment: And you want a bundle of us to take your code and push it through a simulator where we are likely to get the same result, wasting everybody's time. Then what?

Comment: I'm not forcing anyone. If you think it's a wastage of your time then you don't need to approach.

Comment: The question doesn't provide a problem statement and your comment the LED output is null is neither accurate nor enlightening. What does happen is after command_num goes out of index range of type in_words_command for signal in_words (`in_word <= in_words(command_num);`) you'll get a bounds check error and your simulation will stop as a result. There are two cures a) don't run the simulation long enough to go out of bounds, b) operate `command_num` so it doesn't go out of index range for in_words. Generally testbenches aren't written depending on run time (they can stop when done).

Comment: Stopping `command_num` from going out of index range of `in_words` can be done with a conditional assignment statement - `command_num <= 0 after 5000 ms when command_num = in_words'HIGH else command_num + 1 after 5000 ms;` This would cause the index to wrap. The clock can be stopped by conditional signal assignment testing NOW (a function without a parameter that returns the current simulation time).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried your approach already by running the simulation for 80 s to get all the states. However, still, the LED output shows an incorrect result. Can you please run the code by yourself once and share the simulated wave with me?

Comment: You still haven't specified a problem. What is the incorrect result and when? What should the result be? You're not providing a [mcve], it's not verifiable without knowing what's wrong. Without knowing when in the simulation you consider the results incorrect someone can't provide anything you'd find useful over the 80 seconds the simulation will run before error. The dump file is megabytes.

Comment: Now I'm using GHDL and when I would like to compile the testbench, it shows dut (device under test) is not bound. I've used your command already. Do you've any solution for that?

Answer (score -1):

```
if freq_counter = 0 then 
  freq_counter := led_freq_count;
  LED_switch <= not LED_switch;
else
  freq_counter := freq_counter - 1;
end if;

if duty_counter = 0 then 
  duty_counter := 100;
else
  duty_counter := duty_counter - 1;
end if;
```

Comment: For extra credit, add code to change the brightness smoothly (ramp up or down) from one setting to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is it possible for you to run the code once and share the simulated result with me?